# Execute jQuery code after all CSS rules have been applied

Tags: jquery, layout, usability

`$(document).ready()` executes the code when all HTML elements have been loaded.

How to execute jQuery code after all of the CSS rules have been applied?

I have few stylesheets linked to the page and it takes some time to load the page. Element layout changes during the time of the loading.

For usability purposes I need to correct the element layout after all of them have target sizes. Otherwise I get wrong sizes of those elements.

Now I do it on focus or after some timeout, but need this after the page loads.

Comment: $(document).ready()

This line means the jQuery should only start executing once your entire page is loaded. There may be an issue with the CSS.

Comment: window.load should do , it will till all the images loads also

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$(window).load()` fires after the whole page (images, CSS, etc.) has loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I was playing with `$(document).load()`, but I just needed `$(window).load()`

Comment: @Emmett How would I get this to work if I am dynamically injecting CSS? thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).load(function() {

 // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images

 alert("window is loaded");

});
```