# Running Javascript after CSS is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that depends on the css being loaded.
I load css on the header before I load the javascripts on the footer

I tried the javascript with `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var bar_position, width;
  bar_position = $('body').height() - 38;
  width = $('body').width();
  console.log(bar_position);
  if (width <= 480) {
    console.log("Entered");
    $('#accounts-bar').css("top", bar_position);
  }
});
```

I tried `$(window).ready`, `$(window).load`, but all of them fail.

Comment: You need $(document).ready, not window.

Comment: Why you dont use `{}` in your block statement? Your code is confusing...

Comment: `$(document).ready` or just `$->` by the way, is this CoffeeScript?

Comment: @Tamlyn CoffeScript? If so, OP should have the correct tag on the question

Comment: @JuanMendes it possible, but **daniel** call this javascript bringing more confusion to post

Comment: Ah everyone focused on coffeescript vs javascript. Its coffeescript, but still even doing $(document).ready doesn't work. My javascript is loaded before the css is. Removing the coffeescript.

Comment: What does not work? Needs details to explain your problem.

Comment: Well the javascript modifies the CSS, but the css is not loaded yet so it doesn't. I need a way to wait for the css to load.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute jQuery code after all CSS rules have been applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441384/execute-jquery-code-after-all-css-rules-have-been-applied)

Answer (score 3):

You code is really messed up (unless you are using CoffeeScript.) This is what it should be:

```
$(function () {
    bar_position = $('body').height() - 38; //38 is the size of the bar 
    width = $('body').width();
    console.log(bar_position);
    if (width <= 480) { //480 is the mobile width
        console.log("Entered");
        $('#accounts-bar').css("top", bar_position);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript comments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Code_comments) are not `#`, they are `//`

**wrong**

```
bar_position = $('body').height() - 38 #38 is the size of the bar
```

**right**

```
bar_position = $('body').height() - 38 //38 is the size of the bar
```

And there are a bunch of other errors where that code would not run. Guessing you missed a tag and this is not pure JavaScript since it is indented for block scope and missing braces/closures all over.

Comment: it appears he's using coffeescript

Comment: Yes, in Coffeescripts, comments are put like that.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS being loaded in the header, JS in the footer, and wrapped in a doc-ready, you should be fine as far as the CSS being applied before the JS code is executed. I'm guessing the reason your element has no width is that it is `display: none;`, or contains only floated elements, or something along those lines. In other words - I think this is a CSS issue, not a JS timing issue. Try going into your Firebug/Chrome console, selecting the element in question, and getting its width.

Comment: No, I actially set a delay of 1000 and then it works. Point being the css is being loaded after.

Answer (score 0):

The [ready event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) should suffice.

> When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties,
>   it's important to reference external stylesheets or embed style
>   elements before referencing the scripts.
>
> In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the
>   dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a
>   handler for the load event instead.

Also, your javascript is invalid.  If it is supposed to be CoffeeScript, you are missing ->:

```
$(document).ready ->
  bar_position = $('body').height() - 38 #38 is the size of the bar 
  width = $('body').width() 
  console.log(bar_position)
  if (width <= 480) #480 is the mobile width
    console.log("Entered");
    $('#accounts-bar').css("top", bar_position)
  return
```

If it's supposed to be JavaScript, you have more issues:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    bar_position = $('body').height() - 38; //38 is the size of the bar 
    width = $('body').width(); 
    console.log(bar_position);
    if (width <= 480) //480 is the mobile width {
      console.log("Entered");
      $('#accounts-bar').css("top", bar_position);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code here
});
```