# How do I access a typescript module in plain javascript?

Tags: typescript

Might be doing this wrong as I am new to typescript, but I have created a module, which I think from watching tutorials all day, let's me create what in C# would be a class, and I've done so like this:

```
export default class MyClass {

}
```

Now, it's my understanding that to create a new instance of this class, in typescript, I would do this:

```
import t from './MyClass';
var something = new t();
```

However, in my case my file is a js file, not a ts file, because I need to do it on the bottom of a html page.

However I can't figure out how, as doing `new Myclass()` gives me a not defined error.

I am struggling with the concept of import and export despite watching several tutorials so I could be doing things wrong, but I just want to create a clean project and it has lead mt to believe this is the way to do that.

I should also add that I had to add my module like this:

`<script type="module" src="~/Scripts/Proj/MyClass.js"></script>`

I have never used `type="module"` before, it just didn't work without it and I found it on a random SO post.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way for a global script to access a module.  Instead, you'll need to write a module that copies all the things you want to use in global scripts into global variables (i.e., properties of the window).  You can do this directly in `MyClass.ts` if you like (which I'll do for simplicity) or in a separate module.

A second issue is that [modules are always deferred](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/#defer-by-default), so in order for your global script to run after the module, you'll need to defer your global script using one of the techniques from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394983/how-to-defer-inline-javascript).

Working example:

index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="module" src="./MyClass.js"></script>
<script defer src="global.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

MyClass.ts:

```
export default class MyClass {

}
(<any>window).MyClass = MyClass;
```

global.js:

```
console.log(new MyClass());
```

### Example with simple global TypeScript script

MyClass.ts:

```
class MyClass {}
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="MyClass.js"></script>
<script>
console.log(new MyClass());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Example with TypeScript namespace

MyClass.ts:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
  export class MyClass {}
}
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="MyClass.js"></script>
<script>
console.log(new MyNamespace.MyClass());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is way too complicated to just create a re-usable class in a TS file and use it in my code, without adding itself to the global namespace. There has to be something I'm doing wrong. I just want to do `new MyClass()` on my html page and use it.

Comment: I get a 'define is not defined' error with the above code on this line `define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {`

Comment: If you want to load the TypeScript with `<script type="module">`, then you need to set the `module` compiler option to `es6` to preserve the ES6 module instead of converting it to an AMD module (which will fail unless you use an AMD loader).

Comment: Re "way too complicated": You can use TypeScript without using modules at all.  Just remove the `export default` and your TypeScript file will be a global script that will define `MyClass` globally.

Comment: Hmm, trying typescript to do things correctly, as much like C# as possible with nice classes and separate files etc.

I tried a namespace instead of a module but still couldn't see my class. I tried adding it to the window object and still nothing. 

Not really sure what to do now, trying very hard to learn typescript but if I can't even get a simple thing like this to work after about 10 hours of trying different things over the past 2 days...

I've done all of the pluralsight tutorials on it but there's just so little information about how it all hangs together :S

Comment: OK, let's start really simple.  Does the "Example with simple global TypeScript script" that I have just added work for you?

Comment: Yep - that's pretty much what I started with when I first dabbled with typescript. But then I realised I didn't want it cluttering up the global namespace, so I read about modules and namespaces. Not 100% sure on when to use each one but I tried creating a module, and then had the above problems, so I tried creating a namespace, and still had the same problems.

Comment: How about the above for a namespace?  The example I gave of a module should also have worked if you set the `module` option to `es6` as I said, though it does require copying `MyClass` onto the window.

Comment: Ahha, that worked, I had export namespace when I tried it, I removed export and it worked (kept it on the class though)! Thanks. Can't really tell if I should just write my application like this or if I should use modules really, I am not sure what the advantages are. None of the videos I watched really made it clear. Plus there is massive confusion over modules/namespaces sometimes being the same thing.