# Wait for scripts with type="module" to finish before running the next script

Tags: javascript, html, es6-modules

At the bottom of the `body` tag inside my html document I have 2 script tags with `type="module"`. Below that I have a script tag with some embedded code that depends on the result of the previous 2 scripts.
Is there a way to make sure that this code only gets executed once the first 2 scripts have finished?

```
<script src="./src/js/script1.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="./src/js/script2.js" type="module"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Code inside this tag should only run after the 2 previous script tags have been executed
  console.log('Hello SO');
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by results? are the scripts running async code?

Comment: "*I have a script tag with some embedded code that depends on the result of the previous 2 scripts*" - that's what module dependencies are made for! Use `import` declarations

Answer (score 2):

`<script>` tags with `type="module"` are automatically given a `defer` attribute (see [load and execute order of scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts)), so to make the third  tag run after, it also needs to be deferred. Since this isn't possible with inline scripts (as mentioned in the comments), you can either move the script to another file and reference it with the `src` attribute or wrap the code in a event listener for the `DOMContentLoaded` event (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41395202/19461620)

Using an external script file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js" defer></script>
```

`script.js`

```
  // Code inside this tag should only run after the 2 previous script tags have been executed
  console.log('Hello SO');
```

Using a `DOMContentLoaded` callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        (function($) {
            //do something with b-lazy plugin, lightbox plugin and then with flexslider
        })(jQuery);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: _"This attribute must not be used if the src attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would have no effect."_ - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 2):

Make your inline script a module one and `import` the required resources from there:

```html
<script type="module">
  import result1 from "./src/js/script1.js";
  import result2 from "./src/js/script2.js";
  console.log('Hello SO');
</script>
```

[Live example](https://low-massive-dish.glitch.me) [Source](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/low-massive-dish)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the onload callback of scripts to make sure the order is maintained.

```
let scriptsLoaded = 0;

//script1
var script1 = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'module';
script.src ='./src/js/script1.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);

//script2
var script2 = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'module';
script.src ='./src/js/script2.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);

script1.onLoad = function () {
    scriptsLoaded++;
    if(scriptsLoaded == 2) //load third script
}

script2.onLoad = function () {
    scriptsLoaded++;
    if(scriptsLoaded == 2) //load third script
}
```