# editor.html:41 Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined at editor.html:41:19

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a blog site and trying to store it in Firestore; However, this issue persists during the Firebase setup. I cannot use the import function because they cause an error, and changing the script type to module causes another error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>blog editor</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/editor.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="banner">
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="banner-upload" hidden>
        <label for="banner-upload" class="banner-upload-btn"><img src="img/upload.png" alt="upload banner"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="blog">
        <textarea type="text" class="title" placeholder="Blog title..."></textarea>
        <textarea type="text" class="article" placeholder="Start writing here..."></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="blog-options">
        <button class="btn dark publish-btn">publish</button>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="image-upload" hidden>
        <label for="image-upload" class="btn grey upload-btn">Upload Image</label>
    </div>

    <script type="module" defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script type="module" defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script defer>
      let firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "<your-api-key>",
          authDomain: "<your-auth-domain>",
          projectId: "<your-project-id>",
          storageBucket: "<your-storage-bucket>",
          messagingSenderId: "<your-messaging-sender-id>",
          appId: "<your-app-id>"
      };

   *   const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);*
      const db = firebase.firestore();
    </script>

    <script defer src="js/editor.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong. I already tried all sorts of alternatives here, and each has an issue. I can't get past it. I mat my wits end here, so I turn to yall on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can't defer inline scripts. See [How to defer inline Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394983/how-to-defer-inline-javascript)